# ruby on rails star rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi so im trying to display a star rating on the website so far i've got the ratings in a form of a number however i want to times that number and display the equall amount of stars using a loop or somehting alike i.e. if the rating is 4 then 4 star pictures get printed out, any ideas?

my code so far...

number_with_precision(product.no_of_stars, :precision => 1) // this line prints out the number ans works just fine

im trying to do something like this...

product.no_of_stars.times do |i| 
 image_tag("/images/star.jpg") 
end

but it keeps saying "undefined method `times' for #"

Comment: When you see a solitary `#` in HTML it's probably because Ruby will print objects surrounded by `<` and `>`. Since <Float:0x25238235> or whatever isn't a valid HTML tag, your browser will ignore it. Look at the HTML source to help you see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your `product.no_of_stars` is returning a float, whereas only Integers (or perhaps Fixnums) can respond to `times`; if you're happy with ignoring any fractions, you could try:

```
product.no_of_stars.to_i.times do ...
```

Or if you always want an integer, then perhaps change your DB to use an integer column?

Otherwise it might work better to use javascript for your star rating; a quick google will give you plenty of results.

Comment: thanks works great only now the image is too big for the page, i'll need to resize that but thanks

Comment: @ArvidBoome, if you think this response correctly answers your question, then it's both helpful and polite to mark this as correct.